# Javascript chaining a method to the result of recursive calls

Tags: javascript, recursion, slice

I'm trying to return a string from a recursive call and then slice it, but the behavior of the slice is strange.

Given

```
let first = arr => arr.slice(0, 1)
let rest = arr => arr.slice(1)

let join = function join(arr, connector) { 
  return !arr.length ? '' : first(arr) + connector + join(rest(arr), connector)
}

let nums = [1, 2, 34, 45, 100]
```

where join creates a string from array values with a concatenator as

```
join(nums, '-')
```

returns

```
"1-2-34-45-100-"
```

and then to slice off that last '-'

```
"1-2-34-45-100-".slice(0, -1)
```

returns

```
"1-2-34-45-100"
```

or

```
function f() {
  return ("1-2-34-45-100-").slice(0, -1)
}
f()
```

returns
    "1-2-34-45-100"

Simple enough. So why is it that adding a slice to the result of the above recursive calls like

```
let join = function join(arr, connector) { 
    return ( !arr.length ? '' : first(arr) + connector + join(rest(arr), connector) )
      .slice(0, -1); 
}
```

produces this?

```
join(nums, '-')
// -> "1-2-34-45"
// shouldn't this be "1-2-34-45-100" ?
```

or even stranger,

```
join([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], '-')
// -> "1-2-3-4-5-6"
```

Is the slice getting involved in the recursive calls?

Comment: You need to add some `console.log`s so you can see what is happening - or even better, learn how to use a javascript debugger such as the one that comes with Chrome.

Comment: Do you not think the slice() runs on each recursion? It runs on every call

Comment: @epascarello that's my assumption. is that incorrect? if so, I still can't reason with the results.

Comment: because the code is this:
`function join (...) { var x = ( !arr.length ? '' : first(arr) + connector + join(rest(arr), connector) )
      .slice(0, -1);  return x }`

Comment: Also recursion for join() seems so weird....

Comment: @epascarello thanks much for the code but I'm getting the same result with that

Comment: That is the SAME CODE as what you have written.... I was showing you what your code was doing. You would have to call slice where you call the function the first time, not in every iteration.

Comment: @epascarello ah finally i see it. i assumed the nesting of the recursion wouldn't include the slicing, but i was wrong. this might seem like a silly question to you, but you showed me what i was looking for. thanks a lot!

Comment: @epascarello if you want me to accept an answer from you just post anything below and i'll and accept it and elaborate on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's a problem with your `first` function

```
// first :: [a] -> [a] WUPS
let first = arr =>
  arr.slice(0, 1)
```

`first` should be returning the first element, **not** a single-element array containing the first item

```
// first :: [a] -> a
const first = xs =>
  xs[0]
```

---

Next, we think about the complete [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (input) of your function. Your function accepts an array of strings. The array can contain 0, 1, or more strings and we need your function to work for all cases of that – the [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) (output) is of the type string; `join` should *always* return a string

```
// contract
join ([])      == ''
join ([a])     == a
join ([a,b])   == a + '-' + b
join ([a,b,c]) == a + '-' + b + '-' + c
```

Encoding this in a recursive function is trivial in JavaScript – notice there's no need to keep track of array indexes or worry about incrementing an iterator – just think about fulfilling that contract

```js
const first = xs =>
  xs[0]

const rest = xs =>
  xs.slice (1)

const join = xs => {
  switch (xs.length) {
    case 0:   return ''
    case 1:   return first (xs)
    default:  return first (xs) + '-' + join (rest (xs))
  }
}

console.log (join ([]))               // ''
console.log (join (['a']))            // 'a'
console.log (join (['a', 'b']))       // 'a-b'
console.log (join (['a', 'b', 'c']))  // 'a-b-c'
```

Or course our function could be vastly improved if we allow the user to specify the joining string

```js
const first = xs =>
  xs[0]

const rest = xs =>
  xs.slice (1)

const join = (y, xs) => {
  switch (xs.length) {
    case 0:   return ''
    case 1:   return first (xs)
    default:  return first (xs) + y + join (y, rest (xs))
  }
}

console.log (join ('&', []))               // ''
console.log (join ('&', ['a']))            // 'a'
console.log (join ('&', ['a', 'b']))       // 'a&b'
console.log (join ('&', ['a', 'b', 'c']))  // 'a&b&c'
```

Comment: naomik i've read a lot of your posts - always good stuff. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You put the `slice` in join function will cause it `slice` every time when run `join()`.

And because you do recursion in join function, the `slice` will be called more than once.

Try to call the slice when finish `join()`. It will work.

```
let first = arr => arr.slice(0, 1)
let rest = arr => arr.slice(1)

let join = function join(arr, connector) { 
    return ( !arr.length ? '' : first(arr) + connector + join(rest(arr), connector) )
}

join([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], '-').slice(0, -1)
```

#### Update

Based on your concern, you can write the code in this way:

```
const join = function(arr, connector) {
  const first = arr => arr.slice(0, 1)
  const rest = arr => arr.slice(1)

  const joinChain = function(arr, connector) {
    return ( !arr.length ? '' : first(arr) + connector + joinChain(rest(arr), connector) );
  }
  return joinChain(arr, connector).slice(0, -1);
}

join([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], '-')
```

Comment: thanks - that's true you could just chain onto Sting.prototype but we wanted a join function that would do it all.

Comment: @Harold based on your concern, I update the code. Use a join function to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should just adjust the logic to avoid the trailing connector.

```js
let first = arr => arr.slice(0, 1)
let rest = arr => arr.slice(1)

let join = function join(arr, conn) { 
  return !arr.length ? "" :
          first(arr) + (arr.length === 1 ? "" : (conn + join(rest(arr), conn)))
}

let nums = [1, 2, 34, 45, 100]

console.log(join(nums, "-"));
```

---

A "rest parameter" on a nested function can make this a little simpler.

```js
let join = function join(arr, conn) {
  return j(...arr);

  function j(head, ...rest) {
    return (head || "") + (rest.length ? (conn + j(...rest, conn)) : "")
  }
}

let nums = [1, 2, 34, 45, 100]

console.log(join(nums, "-"));
```